# Grid inside tabpanel gets broken

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a tabpanel. Inside a second tab I have a grid. From code point view everyting is ok, everything is absolutely ok. And if I move the grid to the first tab, then evrything works nice. The problem is somehow related to the fact that when we put a grid to a tab which is not active, then it get broken. This is how it looks like:

[image: bug]

Comment: How does it get broken? Any errors or problem with repainting grid?

Comment: I see no errors in the console. As fo how it it gets broken - you can see it in the image.

Comment: check for `layout` property in grid definition object

Comment: I checked this property by `console.log(this.layout)` inside afterrender listener. And get - `Object { id: "fit-1516", layoutCount: 0, owner: Object, initialized: true, overflowPadderEl: null }`

Comment: As for definition itself, it lacks `layout` property.

Comment: Besides, I should add that tabpanel has this property - `deferredRender:false`

Comment: Oh, I found what was wrong with that. Internally, even though we set `deferredRender:false` there is a major difference between first activated tab and all other tabs. And this difference is that the first tab has `this.html` property, whereas unactivated tabs do not. Instead they have `this.body.dom.innerHTML`. So, in some sense this is extjs 4 bug